# Remove Thunderbird's (empty) Personal Address Book

Tags: thunderbird, address-book

How is it possible to remove Thunderbirds Personal Address Book (PAB)? It's empty and I don't use it because I use Googles address book.

The respective file in my profile, `abook.mab` is not listed in the `prefs.js` so no solution based on altering the preferences works. It also had no success to remove or rename `abook.mab`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the extended configurations area set the value of "ldap_2.servers.pab.dirType" to -1 
I found this solution also while searching for that, but do not remember whom to praise for that. Cudos.

Answer (score 0):

Hide with CSS :

1°Open help menu in thunderbird>troubleshooting information> line profile directory>open directory
2°Createa a folder called "Chrome"
3°In this folder "UserContent.css"(userChrome.css somehow does not affect the contact tab)
4°Add in it :

li[aria-label="Personal Address Book"] {
display: none !important;
}

or

#booksPane ul li[title="Personal Address Book"] {
display: none !important;
}